# How can i analyze numbers with certain conditions set?

Tags: excel

Yes i need a computer program that can look at a group of 50 sets of 5 numbers and generate me 5 numbers from them 50 sample sets where each number to be generated has certain conditions. Like the 1st number that will be generated as one of the 5 numbers generated needs to have only came up with say the 3rd and 4th and 5th number to be generated from the 50 sets of 5 sample numbers as the 1st number condition. The 2nd and 3rd and 4th and 5th numbers will have conditions that will need to be set as well. And the program will show me the pair or pairs of 5 numbers that meet those conditions if those conditions exist.

I tried to do an excel vba but it'll only tell me how the numbers came up in relation to each other vs me putting in the relation part and it gives me the the numbers.

Comment: randbetween() comes to mind. BTW starting with "I need" and showing zero effort as to what you have tried tends to limit the responses you might get.

Comment: List out some acceptable solutions and what you tried in VBA. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also this calls for examples. What would be an acceptable range of output numbers and why?

Comment: Lets say i got 3 sets of 5 numbers. 1,5,10,25,35...3,10,15,25,35.  6,8,13,29,32. I have a program made with vba that tells me if a number came up with another one of the other numbers or not thats one of my test numbers of 5. So if 5,10,15,25,35 is my test numbers. Then it says 1st number came up with the 2nd and 4th and 5th... 2nd number came up with the 1st, 3rd, 4th and 5th. 3rd number came up with the 2nd,4th and 5th. 4th number came up with the 1st, 2nd,3rd and 5th. And the 5th number came up with the 1st, 2nd,3rd and 4th number in the set of 3 rows of 5 numbers...

Comment: I been trying to get it to work the opposite way where it will produce the numbers based on the conditions the numbers need to have in relation to each other to be grouped together. And its just a different lottery strategy i been working on. But can't seem to find anyone i know who can write code in that way...